# Execute remaining commands only if preceding matched

Tags: sed

Is there a way to tell `sed` to not run the remaining commands for lines that didn't match preceding commands?

Here's an example:

```
sed -rn '/^pT_yy +/{s/[^ ]+ +//;s/ +/,/g;p}'
```

I'd like to match `^pT_yy +` and substitute it in one go, without duplicating code for matching and substituting.

I initially had

```
sed -rn 's/^pT_yy +//;s/ +/,/gp'
```

but this prints lines that don't starts with `^pT_yy +` as if they passed though `sed -r 's/ +/,/'`, and I don't want those lines at all.

Comment: adding sample input and expected output would help in understanding your problem better and help in testing too when suggesting a solution..

Comment: you are probably looking for https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the test command:

> t label (test) Branch to label only if there has been a successful
>   substitution since the last input line was read or conditional branch
>   was taken. The label may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is
>   started.

[Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Example (skip the second if 1st command fails):

```
sed 's/e/1/;!t;s/t/2/g' <<< "test string"
```

Prints:

```
21s2 s2ring
```

It does the second substitution since the first one succeeds.

If you revert the condition (skip the second if first succeeds):

```
sed 's/e/1/;t;s/t/2/g' <<< "test string"
```

It prints:

```
t1st string
```

here it skipped the second one because the first command succeeded.

Comment: Wrote an example, your snippet is not eye friendly.

Comment: But you will write `sed -rn 's/^pT_yy +//;!t;s/ +/,/gp'`

Comment: This still prints lines that don't start with `pT_yy`.

Comment: This works for me: `sed -r 's/^pT_yy +//;tf;d;: f s/ +/,/gp'`. I don't know why the first version doesn't work :)

Comment: The second version works for me, too. Thanks. There's a typo, though. That `p` at the end makes everything print twice, since there's no `-n` anymore.